Какая архитектура программы лучше всего подходит для MDI-интерфейса?
Многодокументный интерфейс подразумевает, что в программе будет минимум две формы - Главная форма (контейнер) и форма, экземпляры которой будут создаваться внутри главной.
Первоначально я планировал отталкиваться в своей программе от классического MVC, но если один контроллер будет отвечать и за главную форму, и за дочерние, мне это кажется существенным нарушением, которое переусложнит контроллер.
Но ведь программы с MDI-интерфейсом достаточно распространены, и наверняка для них есть уже выверенная и хорошо подходящая архитектура. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая именно?
P.S. На данный момент мне видится наиболее удачной следующая конфигурация:


Если отталкиваться от классического mvc, то у вас не должно быть проблем с формами. Есть простое, но эффективное правило использования контроллеров: один контроллер - одна сущность/сервис. Почему вы думаете, что две формы на один контроллер это плохо? К примеру, многоуровневая микросервисная система может повсеместно использовать те или иные api контроллеры для вызова нужных данных. Вы можете пойти путём итерирования разработки - если вам, после реализацие, покажется что структура неравномерно сложная, можете упростить её в будущем. Просто вынести функционал из одного контроллера в другой

Спасибо за ответ! Один контроллер - одна сущность. Замечательно, именно поэтому я и думаю что две формы на один контроллер это плохо. Контроллер связывает представление и модель, и имеет ссылки на них. Добавление контроллеру ответственности в виде еще одной формы потребует хранить ссылку на нее, а значит контроллер станет зависим от конкретной реализации вида. Если вы допускаете ввод в программу отдельного контроллера для второй формы, не могли бы обрисовать, какие объекты должны быть созданы в самом начале (в Main-е) и как этот дополнительный контроллер будет общаться с моделью?

Думаю, что можно каждый контроллер под отдельную форму для обработки событий именно формы. В контроллеры инжектим нужные сервисы по надобности. Каждый запрос обрабатывается соответствующим событием. Иными словами, один контроллер - одна форма. На контроллере некое количество событий для обработки всех нужных действий. Каждое действие имеет свою модель Dto для передачи информации. Среди других архитектур для MDI есть ещё MVP, MVVM или Document-View (Одно окно - один документ). Всё зависит от бизнес-логики программы

Благодарю! А есть ли изящный способ для организации взаимодействия между контроллерами? Главной форме по сути доступ к модели почти не нужен, поэтому я считаю логичным организвать этот доступ через контроллер дочерних форм. Но вот посредством чего... События уже используются - контроллер главной формы ловит ее события. Создавать дублирующие события и подписывать на них контроллер дочерней формы? Опять же, без ссылок друг на друга это вряд ли получится. В общем, запутался, и не понимаю как правильно. P.S. Если что, я еще только учусь.

Какое именно взаимодействие вам нужно организовать? Что-то с рода передачи документов и т.д. в дочерние формы можно сделать через аргументы конструктора формы или методов. Из дочернего в родительские я бы пошёл способом callback-ов. А вообще, лучше всё через сервисы и БД делать, т.к. БД предназначено для хранения состояние объектов, но это в том случае, если вам нужно сохранять их промежуточное состояние. Тут способом много, конкретнее ничего сказать не смогу к сожалению

Если вам помогли мои комментарии, я могу вынести в отдельный ответ, если хотите

Взаимодействие следующее. Все взаимодействие с данными, файловой системой и т.д. происходит дочерних формах. Поэтому они со своим контроллером и моделью и образуют MVC. Главная же форма с моделью не взаимодействует вообще, а лишь инициирует в контроллере дочерних форм процесс открытия документов, создания новых форм и обработку данных. Т.е. своего рода пульт. Меня интересует, как организовать это коррекно, т.к. мне кажется, что будет неправильно, если контроллер доч. форм будет знать, что получает эти команды от главной формы. Может вообще создавать доч. формы внутри главной, и не париться...

@Faraday добавил картинку для пояснения того, как именно я представляю взаимодействие компонентов в программе.

Да, такая структура может отлично подойти

@Faraday мне тоже нравится, но я не понимаю как снизить зависимость двух контроллеров друг от друга. Мне представляется, что идеальным вариантом было бы сделать так, чтобы контроллер дочерних форм вообще не догадывался бы, что обрабатывает события от главной формы. Но не понимаю, как это сделать правильно. Если напишете ответ с примером, это будет отлично. Заранее спасибо!

Для MDI проектов можно использовать один из следующих распространённых архитектурных паттернов:

MVC
MVP
MVVM
Document-View

Вы можете использовать любой из представленных в силу вашего понимания каждого из них. Рассмотрим же организацию паттерна MVC. Вообще стоит отметить, что более правильно было бы использовать MVVM, который действует по правилам MVC, но используется для настольных приложений и имеет некоторые особенности.
Если выходить из классического применения MVC, контроллер должен отвечать за некоторую узкую область и предоставлять все необходимые методы для обработки данный, которые связаны с этой областью.
Исходя из требований в комментариях под вопросом, могу припустить, что было бы не плохой использовать отдельные контроллеры для каждой из форм. Управление дочерними формами можно сделать через передачу соответствующих параметров в контроллер, а так же можно хранить ссылки на дочерние формы и вызывать некоторые методы из родительской формы

Взаимодействие с родительским контроллером можно реализовать через callback функцию, которую можно передать в конструкт при инициализации, либо в метод дочернего контроллера при его вызове. Логика выполнения примерно изображена на следующем рисунке (Простите за навыки рисования)

Так вы не будете перегружать основной контроллер действиями, которые ему не принадлежат, а сможете вынести их на уровень дочерних контроллеров, а так же сможете сохранить зависимость между контроллерами при надобности.
Для сохранения зависимости и общения между контроллерами я бы всё же выбрал бы stateless подход. Суть в том, что бы всё взаимодействие проходило через базу данных либо сервисы с сохранением состояние. Но стоит отметить, такой подход вряд ли подойдёт, если вы хотите динамические изменения в программе без сохранения состояние. Структура такого подхода на следующем рисунке


Благодарю за подробное разъяснение!

Есть много выверенных и подходящих архитектур (MVC, MVP, MVVM) у которых у всех общий недостаток - они слишком абстрактны и мало отвечают на вопрос о том, как же на самом деле следует писать код.
На самом деле, MVC настолько абстрактна, что на Хабре до сих пор периодически спорят чем именно является форма - моделью, контроллером или видом
Поэтому, предлагаю спуститься немного ниже. И так, у вас есть две формы, и вам надо как-то связать их. И, как вы сами заметили, желательно сделать так, чтобы дочерняя форма не знала о родительской.
Сделать это можно тремя способами.
Способ 1. Через общую модель.
Дочерняя форма может поменять свойство в модели (желательно через дата-биндинг), модель отправит событие, главная форма отреагирует (желательно через дата-биндинг). В обратную сторону это тоже работает.
Разумеется, это не означает, что модели у главной и дочерней форм должны быть буквально общими. Помните, что модель, как и остальные компоненты MVC, может делиться на подмодели, как независимые, так и иерархически связанные. Передавайте в дочернюю форму ту часть модели, которая ей нужна.
Способ 2. Через события
Дочерняя форма может объявить событие, а главная форма - на него подписаться.
Способ 3. Через интерфейс
На случай, когда событий недостаточно или просто слишком много.
Дочерняя форма может запросить в конструкторе некоторый интерфейс (скажем, IChildFormOwner или IChildFormHost), а главная форма - его реализовать (напрямую или через внутренний класс).
Способ 4. Через задачи (Task)
Редкий способ, который применим, как правило, ровно в одном случае - в формах-диалогах, задача которых - запросить у пользователя данные. В таком случае жизненный цикл формы можно неплохо уложить в асинхронный метод, вроде ShowAsync:
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource tcs = new();

    private void bthOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult();
        Close();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        Close();
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
    }

    public Task ShowAsync()
    {
        Show();
        Activate();
        return tcs.Task;
    }


Благодарю за подробный ответ! Завтра на свежую голову еще почитаю, обдумаю, но пока мне кажется что под мой случай подходит разве что Способ 1, если дать главной форме доступ к модели. Как я писал выше - главная форма это своего рода пульт. Т.е. ей ни на что реагировать не нужно - она просто отдает команды. Не нужен даже доступ к модели, строго говоря. Так и чешутся руки просто присобачить ее к дочернему контроллеру)) Разом всех проблем как ни бывало, кроме растоптанного чувства собственного достоинства, т.к. не смог найти хорошее решение)
